# Is that possible to use php debug or something debug tool on VScode on Laravel artisan serve on?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I write a PHP/Laravel code with VScode.

The version of Laravel is 6.20

I would like to use break point and check values of variables and arrays.

I tried to install the extension that called Xdebug.

I clicked triangle button.

When the application started (php artisan serve) , it seemed to stop at the break point I put.
However, debug console showed.

```
Failed initializing connection 1: connection closed (on close)
```

I would like to know the steps to use a debug tools that allows break point.

launch.json

```
   "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 8000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](https://tighten.com/blog/configure-vscode-to-debug-phpunit-tests-with-xdebug/) which explains the steps required.

Comment: I tied to install with terminal. 

% brew install php71-xdebug
and
% brew install php74-xdebug
However, No formulae found in taps error happned.

Resolving deltas: 100% (459154/459154), done.
Tapped 4013 casks (4,085 files, 327.4MB).
Warning: No available formula with the name "php71-xdebug".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: Are you even using a Mac? You might need to alter some of the commands for your operating system (i.e. `php-xdebug` rather than `php71-xdebug`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why it's closing the debug connections in your case.

But what you can try is just to start using dockerized environment. It will work. I've written a tutorial on how to set it up. There are some Windows-specific details, but it should work on Mac too. Hopefully, it will help https://blog.devsense.com/2022/laravel-on-docker